# Finding Monitor/Screen on which mouse pointer is present

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse

I will start from beginning, I aw working on an application which will span over multiple monitors, each monitor will contain a single WPF window and these windows are controled using a single viewmodel class. now lets say i have a button on all the windows at 200,300 (x,y) and i want that this button should be responsible for a tool on same window, while all rest are responsible for the application.
When i try to get current mouse position or last click position i get position relative to the current monitor , i.e. in this case 200,300, irrespective of in what screen i am on.

following sre the code i tried for getting mouse position

1. ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   internal struct Win32Point
   {
       public Int32 X;
       public Int32 Y;
   };

   public static Point GetMousePosition()
   {
       Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
       GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
       return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
   }
   ```
2. `Point point = Control.MousePosition;`
3. `Mouse.GetPosition(null);`

following is the code which should return me the screen no.

```
private int ConvertMousePointToScreenIndex(System.Windows.Point mousePoint)
    {
        //first get all the screens 
        System.Drawing.Rectangle ret;

        for (int i = 1; i <= System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Count(); i++)
        {
            ret = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[i - 1].Bounds;
            if (ret.Contains(new System.Drawing.Point((int)mousePoint.X, (int)mousePoint.Y)))
                return i - 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I always get screen as 0 :( 
Please help me in getting appropriate value

Comment: `Cursor.Position` will return the non-relative position -(x,y)..+(x,y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks KnottytOmo, it worked now, may be there was something else wrong at that moment. 
I changed my code to

```
 private int ConvertMousePointToScreenIndex(Point mousePoint)
    {
        //first get all the screens 
        System.Drawing.Rectangle ret;

        for (int i = 1; i <= Screen.AllScreens.Count(); i++)
        {
            ret = Screen.AllScreens[i - 1].Bounds;
            if (ret.Contains(mousePoint))
                return i - 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and called it as `ConvertMousePointToScreenIndex(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);`

Answer (score 22):

Could you use the `Screen` static class?

For example, something like:

```
Screen s = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
```

Or get the current screen from a particular form using:

```
Screen s = Screen.FromControl(this);
```

With `this` being your Form control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx

Comment: The Points I get are in respect to the monitor and not universal i.e. even on 2nd monitor the point i get is 70,150. which will give me a result as primary monitor i.e screen[0]

Comment: @MustahsanAbdullah, you can use `Cursor.Position`.

Comment: *Why* is `Cursor.Position` not helpful?

Comment: I agree with @AlexK. Can you please explain in more detail why this solution does not work?

Comment: Great answer, thank you, but you can simplify it even more.  Cursor.Position is already a Point.  So `Screen.FromPoint(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y))` can just be `Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position)`