# How do I display my windows unity app on the display from which the shortcut was clicked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a windows unity app and I also have two monitors, every time I launch the app I would like the window to appear from the screen in which I clicked it from, screen 0 or 1. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can make another [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402955/finding-monitor-screen-on-which-mouse-pointer-is-present) to track in which monitor you clicked, and then launch your unity app sending this information.

Or you can simply specify in Unity in which monitor you want to display it, via code or just on the start screen:

[image]

**Edit:**
To activate the Resolution Dialog (in versions below 2019.3) open your project->Project Settings->Resolution and Presentation->Display Resolution Dialog->Enabled

[image]

It's worth noting the warning box, which informs that in further versions of Unity, this will be removed, like in the 2019.3. More info [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/the-display-resolution-dialogue-has-been-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-version.670798/).

Comment: I dont have that start screen, is there a way to enable that?

Comment: @TheGuy920 I've updated the answer, tell me if it helps

Comment: Yes thank you so much!

Comment: @TheGuy920 you're welcome! Remember to mark the answer as correct as other people can find it fast! ^^